# Making SNMP set request on Android 2.2

Tags: android, snmp

I want to make a simple SNMP set request within an Android app.
I just want to set one single value to a device. But I can't make it work.

I tried to use the Snmp4Android.jar package.
I tried importing from org.snmp4j

Right now it fails at some example codes I am following on this line:
transport = new DefaultUdpTransportMapping();
It throws an exception: Permission denied

After adding the INTERNET permission it just stops unexpectedly.

I'm stuck!

Please advise, anyone got an example that works?

Answer (score 0):

I have seen this error occur with ports lower than a certain number. I'm going to assume you are using 161 as it is one of those "default" ports that everyone uses. Unfortunately I believe it is one of those restricted ports. Give it a very high number port. 2001 is the one I work with.